# Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page laravel homestead up

Tags: ubuntu, laravel-5, vagrant, apache2, homestead

when I do **vagrant up** or **homestead up**

and open browser the apache default page is displayed

> **Ubuntu Logo Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page** 
>   *It works!* 
>   This is the default welcome page used to test the correct operation of the Apache2 server
>   after installation on Ubuntu systems. It is based on the equivalent
>   page on Debian, from which the Ubuntu Apache packaging is derived. If
>   you can read this page, it means that the Apache HTTP server installed
>   at this site is working properly. You should replace this file
>   (located at /var/www/html/index.html) before continuing to operate
>   your HTTP server. If you are a normal user of this web site and don't
>   know what this page is about, this probably means that the site is
>   currently unavailable due to maintenance. If the problem persists,
>   please contact the site's administrator. Configuration Overview
>   Ubuntu's Apache2 default configuration is different from the upstream
>   default configuration, and split into several files optimized for
>   interaction with Ubuntu tools. The configuration system is fully
>   documented in /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz. Refer to this
>   for the full documentation. Documentation for the web server itself
>   can be found by accessing the manual if the apache2-doc package was
>   installed on this server. The configuration layout for an Apache2 web
>   server installation on Ubuntu systems is as follows: /etc/apache2/ |--
>   apache2.conf |       `--  ports.conf |-- mods-enabled

the solution is to run commande line: (homestead or vagrant)

1. homestead ssh
2. sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
3. sudo service nginx start
4. exit
5. homestead up